# Align images around another image?

Tags: html, css, particles.js

I want small planetary images to be at random places around the main logo (header img) **at a reasonable distance to make it feel like satellite** around the logo. I am not able to achieve the same with positioning and margining. Also when I insert images, logo offsets down a bit and page become scrollable, I don't want the page to be scrollable. Please help. Thanks!

**Here is my HTML:**

```
    <body>

   <div id="particles-js"></div>

    <!-- UP Satellite -->
    <div id="up_sat">
        <img class="sat sat1" src="images/sat/rocket.png"/>
        <img class="sat sat2" src="images/sat/earth.png"/>
    </div>

    <!--- HEADER - LOGO ------>
    <div id="header"><img src="images/header.png" /></div>

   <!-- DOWN Satellite -->
    <div id="down_sat">
        <img class="sat sat3" src="images/sat/jupiter.png"/>
        <img class="sat sat4" src="images/sat/neptune.png"/>
    </div>

   <!-- Particle Script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
  html, body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #0f1824;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}


/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* ================= MAIN BODY ============== */

#header {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#header img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: can you please create fiddle or codepen so we can check what is actually happening. with image we cannot say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using `display: flex` to position your images? I think this is the most flexible way to achieve a responsive version of what you've described.

Try http://flexbox.help/ to play around with the different types of positioning you can use, and consider how you want the layout to look on different screen sizes. This should help with your scroll issue as well.